# How to add Custom error message in magento

Tags: magento

I included a link named `track your order` in footer. If user click this link without logged in, it should show error message like `please login to track your order`.

I'm new to magento please guide me to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to show this link to "not logged in" users in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

Added because this question appears in Google.

For a yellow "warning" message (the one you probably want for this purpose), use

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Please log in to track your order');
```

For a green "success" message, use

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking successful');
```

For a red "error" message, use

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('There was an error tracking your parcel');
```

Answer (score 2):

put this code in your controller

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if (!$session->getCustomerId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('You are not logged in');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Set Your Message.

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addSuccess("Add success message"); 
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError("Please login");
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addNotice("Add notification message");
```

> 2. Display Your Message in Footer.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
```

> 3.Define Block in Layout. (Optional If use custom Extension Or not Defined)

`<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `addError()` function to include your error message in session

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success Message');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error Message');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addWarning('Warning Message');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Notice Message');
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!